# setting tabbar translucent not working

Tags: ios, swift, object, tabbar

I want to make my tabbar half transparent by setting the translucent value to true. However it is not doing the trick. I have a TabBarVC assigned to the tab bar with the following code. The tab bar remains solid

```
class TabBarVC: UITabBarController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // color of background -> This works
    self.tabBar.barTintColor = UIColor.purpleColor()

    // color when selected -> This works
    self.tabBar.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()

    // This does not work
    self.tabBar.translucent = true
}
```

I also tried to do something like

UIColor(red: 246.0/255, green: 246.0/255, blue: 246.0/255, alpha: 0.5)

But it does not seem to work. I did a bit of search on Google but everyones issue seems to differ from mine. Could anyone help me out here?

Thanks,

Comment: can you provide image for that what exactly you want.

Comment: sure. http://i.stack.imgur.com/gYnN1.png    I had red and purple color in my code just to see if they are working. I just want a tabbar that looks abit transparent like the image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're doing is most likely working to adjust the transparency of the tab bar. However, you need to set the corresponding view controllers to be "Under Bottom Bar" in the IB.

Comment: They are all under bottom bar though. The tab bar has five tabs which all have navigation controller. Both the NavVC and the connected VC have undeBottomBars selected

Comment: Try adding self.tabBar?.alpha = 0.3

Comment: @EdwardHung : He's right. Your way of achiveing translucent effect is not right. You have to set the Tab bar Translucent and the view's bottom should be attached to the bottom of the view controller.

Comment: Yes, your bottom constraint is probably "bottom layout guide", when it should view.bottom

Comment: Wow! Thanks for that. I looked pass the fact that my vie wis connected to the bottom layout guid and not the very bottom of the screen! Thats why. Thanks Guys. Much appreciated